Metafictionality in Chapter 11 of David Copperfield?
In Chapter 11 of David Copperfield, the eponymous narrator describes how Mr Micawber, in debtors' prison, draws up a petition for reforming the law around such imprisonment. He and his friend Captain Hopkins get many of their fellow inmates to sign this petition. This episode is framed with some narrative commentary that I'm having trouble understanding. David introduces the incident thus:

By way of going in for anything that might be on the cards, I call to mind that Mr. Micawber, about this time, composed a petition to the House of Commons, praying for an alteration in the law of imprisonment for debt. I set down this remembrance here, because it is an instance to myself of the manner in which I fitted my old books to my altered life, and made stories for myself, out of the streets, and out of men and women; and how some main points in the character I shall unconsciously develop, I suppose, in writing my life were gradually forming all this while.
 Dickens, Charles. David Copperfield. 1850. Introduction by David Gates. Notes by Nitin Govil. New York: Modern Library, 2000. p. 159.

What does this paragraph mean? I cannot understand By way of going in for anything that might be on the cards at all. Or at least, I understand the phrase, but I don't see its connection to what follows. My old books appears to refer to the novels such as Henry Fielding's Tom Jones (1749) or Tobias Smollett's Roderick Random (1748) that David has often read and re-read prior to being sent to London to work in the bottling factory. But is he saying that he made up incidents using scenes from those novels as a pattern? That is, is the narrator admitting that Micawber and the other characters are fictional? It is well known that many incidents in Dickens's own life, such as his labor in a bottling factory and his father's being sent to prison for debt, are the basis for similar incidents in David Copperfield. So is this a metafictional moment where the line between the narrative voice of David and the authorial voice of Dickens is erased?
Likewise, after narrating the story of the petition's signing, the narrator concludes:

As I walked to and fro daily between Southwark and Blackfriars, and lounged about at meal-times in obscure streets, the stones of which may, for anything I know, be worn this moment by my childish feet, I wonder how many of those people were wanting in the crowd that used to come filing before me in review again, to the echo of Captain Hopkins's voice! When my thoughts go back now, to that slow agony of my youth, I wonder how much of the histories I invented for such people hangs like a mist of fancy over well-remembered facts! When I tread the old ground, I do not wonder that I seem to see and pity, going on before me, an innocent romantic boy, making his imaginative world out of such strange experiences and sordid things.
ibid., p. 160.

This seems to mirror and bookend the previously quoted paragraph. Here the narrator appears to be saying, on the one hand, that being separated from the works of Fielding, Smollett, and the other novelists he was wont to read, he used real-life incidents to sate his imagination. On the other, there appears to be some sort of slippage between the grown narrator David's retrospective look at the child David, and the author Dickens's contemplating his character David Copperfield. Whose thoughts are going back to the slow agony of my youth? David's? Dickens's? Are the well-remembered facts over which histories ... invented hang the facts of David's life or Dickens's? Is Dickens saying that due to his having fictionalized parts of his own life in his novels, he is finding it hard to be sure whether an incident he remembers well from his life might actually be what Freud calls a screen memory, an imaginative projection that obscures the real memory?
Unusually for Dickens, some of the prose is actually hard for me to understand. For example, I cannot figure out what is meant by I wonder how many of those people were wanting in the crowd that used to come filing before me in review again, to the echo of Captain Hopkins's voice! I cannot even be sure to whom those people refers.
So: what is going on in these passages? Why do they bracket off the story of the inmates' signing Mr Micawber's petition? Is there a metafictional element to this, where life and art each take the other's place? Or am I reading too much into it?
